# Best practices for developing AIR Application with SQLite

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air, adobe

I am going to start doing a couple of Adobe AIR projects that will be using `SQLite` feature provided by `AIR`. Since this is the first time I am attempting to do this, I would appreciate some pointers, tips and Best Practices for development.

Since this application will be accessing a local db, I think I can open a connection to the database at the start of the app and keep it open till the application closes. Is this a right approach to use here?

How should design my application if I am using an MVC framework like `Mate` or `Cairngorm`?

Should I create some wrapper class to perform the db operations so I can reuse this in some other project? Looking forward to some valuable information...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first and by far most important decision you have to make, is whether you're going to access that database synchronously or asynchronously. They both have their pros and cons, so it will depend on your situation.

**Synchronous**

- simpler architecture
- easier to read
- better suited for small operations
- freezes the app while doing the operations

Good for small scale app

**Asynchronous**

- more complex architecture
- harder to read
- long operations will not freeze the UI
- if you have to sync with a server DB, you can create an interface for both local and remote DB services (e.g. the class `LocalUserService` and `RemoteUserService` both implement an interface that forces them to have a method `saveUser()`)

Good for larger scale app and synchronizing local and remote data.

I tend to almost always opt for the asynchronous approach - since it's more flexible - and abstract the complexity away in ... a wrapper class. So that answers that part of your question.

**Architecture**

I don't like frameworks, so I can't answer your question about `Mate` or -shudder- `Cairngorm`. But here's what I consider a fairly good approach:

- for each entity in your model, create a Data Acces Object (DAO) that will return only raw query results (e.g. `UserDAO` for quering Users). That class should contain only queries.
- matching each DAO create a Builder/Factory that can take those query results and spawn model objects (e.g. UserBuilder)
- this is usually enough for me, but you could also bring the two of them together in a service layer (e.g. UserService). This service layer might also help matching an existing remote service layer to your local services.

As for keeping the connection open. I've always done so and never had any issues with it. I don't exactly know what happens when an application crashes and the connection wasn't properly closed, but this is not Oracle or SQL Server we're talking about. I don't think SQLite will keep open pointers or something since it's just a simple file, but I might be wrong.

**Edit:** some more details on the DAO / Factory pattern (as requested by OP).

An example of a UserDAO with one function:

```
public class PupilDAO extends AsynchronousDAO {

    public function getUserById(id:int, handleResult:Function):Responder {
        return getResults(
            "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = ?", 
            handleResult, [id]
        );
    }

}
```

As you can see, I've abstracted out the complexity into the `AsynchronousDAO` base class, so we can see only the necessary information in UserDAO. The `handleResult` function is a callback that will be called whenever the query is ready, passing in the resultset as an argument. We'll usually pass that resultset into the factory/builder class.

An example of a UserBuilder:

```
public class UserBuilder {

    public function buildUser(record:*):User {
        var user:User = new User();
        user.id = record.user_id;
        user.firstname = record.firstname;
        user.lastname = record.lastname;
        return user;
    }

}
```

This is obviously a simple example, but you can create more complex data structures in the builder. For some info on the difference between the Factory and Builder patterns I recommend Google.

Now let's tie it together in the service class:

```
public class UserService {
    private var dao:UsetDAO;
    private var builder:UserBuilder;

    public UserService(dao:UserDAO, builder:UserBuilder) {
        this.dao = dao;
        this.builder = builder;
    }

    public function getUserById(id:int, handleResult):void {
        var handleResultSet:Function = function(resultSet:SQLResult):void {
            var user:User = builder.buildUser(resultSet.data[0]);
            if (handleResult!= null) handleResult(user);
        }

        dao.getUserById(id, handleResultSet);            
    }

}
```

Finally, let's put the trio to use:

```
var userService = new UserService(new UserDAO(), new UserBuilder());
userService.getUserById(1, handleUser);

function handleUser(user:User):void {
    trace(user);
}
```

For the example I constructed the classes with `new` and passed the dao and the builder as constructor arguments, but you could use injection or singletons or whatever framework you like to do the construction for you.

Comment: I don't have to work with Remote data at the moment, and the app will be to store some info and will mostly be used for searching that info (showing suggessions / querying on each key press). Should be around 500 - 1000 rows. So in this case, should I go for Synchronous or Asynchronous modes?

Comment: Definitely async; otherwise your user may not be able to continue typing while querying. Even if it's not a heavy query, typing happens fast and should stay responsive. There's a specific issue with this case though: a query to match just 2 letters will probably be slower than one to match 5 letters, so the results may come in later. You'll have to find a solution for that :( It's more complex, but unresponsive typing is not an option.

Comment: An alternative would be to load all the data in an ArrayCollection ( since there's only 1000 records, that should be fine) and just filter that as you type with `filterFunction`. Probably much easier.

Comment: Can you tell me more about using the Builder/Factory based on the DAO part, I didn't get that completely.

Comment: If you create the database outside of AIR, be sure to specify INTEGER and not INT or BIGINT or any other integer format.