# Bestpractice: Annotation-based ORM frameworks like Hibernate for Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, orm, air, adobe

### Question

Is there a commonly used framework for AIR that handles mapping objects to and from the built-in SQLite database?  An [Annotation-based ORM framework](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/sqlite_db_api_in_air.edu.html#orm) that is to AIR what Hibernate is to Java?

### Background

We have an AIR application that runs offline.  I need to save/restore complex objects to/from the SQLite database.  Some of these ValueObjects contain references to other ValueObjects.  For example, an Order object contains a Customer object which contains an Address object.

Ultimately, I'd like to add metadata to my objects, like an [Entity] tag and have persistence "just work," with minimal configuration.  I could roll my own ORM solution, effectively writing "Hibernate for AIR" myself, but SURELY someone has already done this.

I've read related posts like [Best practices for developing AIR Application with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088605/best-practices-for-developing-air-application-with-sqlite) that advocate creating DAO's, Builders and Services.  That's a fine solution but, of course, no one wants to reinvent the wheel if it's not 100% necessary.

### Candidates

So far, the best I could find is partial solutions.  I'll keep a running list here:

- [SOFA from Matsiya
  Technology](http://www.matsiya-technology.com/introducing-sofa-an-adobe-air-orm-for-sqlite/) - seems like it never got off the ground
- [FlexORM on RIAForge](http://flexorm.riaforge.org/) - seems dead, judging by the forum
- [JazzRecord](http://www.jazzrecord.org/docs/) - is a JavaScript solution that claims to work with Adobe AIR but documentation is sparse
- [Cairngorm Persistence Library](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/How+to+Use+the+Cairngorm+Persistence+Library) - I hear nothing but bad things about cairngorm & this solution adopts the iBATIS approach, which is not like hibernate
- [AIR ORM in ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/offline_air_orm.edu.html) - not sure if this can be used without coldfusion (if so where do you get cfair.swc)?

Has a framework emerged for this?  Specifically, I'm seeking one like Hibernate that uses Annotations/Metatags to map objects to tables.  Are one of the candidates above actually acceptable?

What are you using succesfully?

All input is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [FxORM](https://github.com/kennichi/FxORM). I worked on a couple of AIR projects with it - it worked fine for quite complex data structure.

Comment: Although I no longer work in ActionScript, this library looks pretty good. I'll accept this answer, for now. Especially since the other suggestion (AS3 SPOd) is now defunct.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [AS3 SPOd](https://github.com/stickupkid/as3-spod/), we use it on a daily basis on a rather large project. No problems so far.