# How connect SQLite with Adobe Air for Android using Flash CS6 and AS3 language?

Tags: android, sqlite, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing a small game for Air Android in flash CS6, this game I'm programming object-oriented with classes written in AS3.

I want you to help me write a class that connects to SQLite from scratch, please!

I googled but only there information to FLEX or code for insert into frames (and i get lost because i don't know that libraries to import), it's not what I want.

I want to create the connection class to use in my class Main.

I hope I have your support, thank you.

Excuse my English but I speak Spanish.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't help you code "from scratch". See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need 'Synchronous' or 'Asynchronous' sqlite connection ? You can see differences here:  - [Best practices for developing AIR Application with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088605/best-practices-for-developing-air-application-with-sqlite) 
1. There is an example for 'async' connection :[SQLConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html#begin()) - you just have to modify and remove transactions part (if you do not need it). 
2. 'sync' is easy and i prefer this way

```
    import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.data.SQLMode; //if you use SQLMode: CREATE | UPDATE | READ
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.data.SQLResult;
import flash.errors.SQLError;

public class SQLiteConn 
{
    private var dbFile:File = new File("pathtofile");
    private var conn:SQLConnection;
    private var stmt:SQLStatement;
    private var arr:Array;


    public function SQLiteConn() 
    {
    }

    //open sqlite DB    
    public function openSQLite():Boolean {
        conn = new SQLConnection;
        if (dbFile.exists) {
            try {
                conn.open(dbFile);
                return true;
            }
            catch (error:SQLError) {
                trace(error.details, error.message);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //execute statement and get result/s
    public function executeStatement(stmtText:String, param1:String, param2:String):Array {
        if (conn.connected) {   
            stmt = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = con;
            stmt.text = stmtText;
            stmt.parameters[0] = param1;
            stmt.parameters[1] = param2;

            try {
                stmt.execute();
                var result:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();

                if (result.data != null) {
                    var total:int = result.data.length;
                    for (var i:int = 0; i < total; i++) {
                            row = result.data[i];
                            arr.push( { id:row.tablerowID } );
                    }
                }
                else {
                    arr.push({id: -1}); //no result/s
                }
            }
            catch (error:SQLError) {
                arr.push({id: -2}); //sqlite error
            }
        }
        else {
            arr.push({id: -2}); //no connection
        }
        return arr;

    }

    //close sqliteConnection
    public function closeSQLiteConn():void {
        if (conn.connected) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

you can also 'dispatch event' from that class - it is your choise :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I opened a new answer because I pasted a fragment of code... Check please